# Can't remove index.php in codeigniter redirecting to localhost.com

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

i have a project having url

```
http://localhost/myproject/
```

naw i have a page that is working

```
http://localhost/myproject/index.php/about
```

but i want to change it to

```
http://localhost/mywesites/about
```

but it's redirecting me to

```
www.localhost.com/about
```

my config.php file is

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/myproject/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

and .htaccess file is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a RewriteBase in your htaccess like this:

```
RewriteBase /mywesites/
```

...does that work?

Answer (score 0):

Replace Your .htaccess file with this code and try :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$1 [PT,L]
```

Comment: its a bit different from yours. check it again.